# Magento - where in tables is order status held?

Tags: magento, status, orders

I was looking through Magento tables trying to figure out where order status is stored - either flat tables or Eav tables.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been stored in sales_flat_order since at least 1.4.2, but it will likely depend on your version of Magento. I believe it might have been stored in EAV in earlier versions but I can't confirm exactly which as I'd never used Magento before that version was released.